# How to fetch a simple json data in android from php

Tags: php, android, json

I am totally new to java/android . I have searched many tutorials over the internet. But those didnt helped me. So I have posted this problem here.

I have simple json data in php like below,

```
[{"title":"re3","notice":"etrf4w"},{"title":"vfdxg","notice":"fdgd"},  {"title":"notice1","notice":"details..."}]
```

I want to show this json data in android as a plain text like below,

Title:re3

notice: etrf4w
.....................
...................

How could I do that. please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you considering using libraries to carry out this json parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the exmaple

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
            case 1:{
                showList();
            }break;
        }
    }

};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    /*
    Your initialization code here
    */

    new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String resp = loadURLData(JSON_URL);

            MainActivity.this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();

            try{
                JSONArray items = new JSONArray(resp);

                for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = item.getString("title");
                    String notice = item.getString("notice");

                    Item it = new Item(title, notice);
                }

                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
            }catch(JSONException jSONEx){
            }
        }

    }.start();
}

private void showList(){
    ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private static String loadURLData(String msgsUrl){
    try{
        URL url = new URL(msgsUrl); 
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);sb.append("\n");
        }
        br.close();
        String resp = sb.toString();

        return resp;
    }catch(IOException iOEx){
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its looking easy for me. But before showing the json data , I must need to fetch the data from php. How can I do that? my php is in localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I said that I am completely new to android/ java. When I try to use your codes , the app crashes and reply "unfortunately <app name> has stopped" .Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseData);
            ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();        
            if(jsonArray != null){
                for(int i=0 ;i < jsonArray.length() ;i++){          
                list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title").toString());     
                            list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("notice").toString());            
                }
            }
return list
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**[** => `JSONArray`

**{** =>  `JSONObject`

```
String response = "Your Response in String format";
JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i = 0; i < new_array.lenght; i++){
     JSONObject obj = new_array.getJSONObject(i);
     // You can get Title from obj.getString("title") like below
     System.out.println("Title:"+obj.getString("title"));
     // You can get Notice from obj.getString("notice") like below
     System.out.println("Notice:"+obj.getString("notice"));
}
```

**JSON Parsing turorials**

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95

Comment: I am new to android/java . So I dont know how to fetch those json data from php .My php code is located at localhost (127.0.0.1). Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
[ // json array node
    { // json object node 
        "title": "re3",
        "notice": "etrf4w"
    },
    {
        "title": "vfdxg",
        "notice": "fdgd"
    },
    {
        "title": "notice1",
        "notice": "details"
    }
]
```

To parse

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
JSOnArray jr = new JSONArray("json string");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = jb.getString("title");
    String notice =jb.getString("notice"); 
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.add("key1",title);
    map.add("key2",notice);
    list.add(map);
}
```

Now you can use the `list` to display the same in a listview.